# can't access any support.microsoft.com pages with IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have a few machines that can't access any support.microsoft.com web page.  I get a simple response of "Internet Explorer Cannot Display this web page".  However, the pages can be accessed with chrome and firefox so connectivity is not an issue.  I have disabled / re-enabled IE, reset all settings in IE, removed add-ons, etc.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, that's a bit ironic.

Comment: Packet capture that sucker.

Comment: did a packet capture with wireshark, but I can't make heads or tails of it.  basically, I'm seeing where they're doing a redirect (also see the url change for a second in the browser to live.com)...followed by some RST, ACKs from my machine to their...then i see the client and server hello for TLS 1.2.  Lastly, I'm seeing TCP segment of reassembled PDU from my machine to theirs and TLS 1.2 "application data" going their server to my machine over and over....this is the only site this happens for.